# Using list comprehension and a dict for regex substitution

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, dictionary, list-comprehension

The following Python 3 code loops through a list of strings and uses a regex to replace some text in each string.

The strings here are straightforward but they are likely to be more complex and far more numerous in a real-world situation, hence my decision to use `re.sub()` rather than `str.replace()`.

```
all = ("this line has no hits",
       "a letter to tom from peter",
       "today bonny went to school",
       "harry made some cake")

for myitem in all:
    newitem = re.sub("harry","sally",myitem)
    newitem = re.sub("tom","jerry",newitem)
    newitem = re.sub("bonny","clyde",newitem)
    print(newitem)
```

This seems to work as expected:

```
>>> this line has no hits
a letter to jerry from peter
today clyde went to school
sally made some cake
>>>
```

In real life there will be a large number of strings, which would make for a messy block of code. I thought there might be a neater, more Pythonic way to do this by defining the regex pairs in a `dict` and using a list comprehension. So I tried this:

```
mydict = {'harry':'sally','tom':'jerry','bonny':'clyde'}

newall = [re.sub(i, mydict[i], j) for i in mydict for j in all]
print(newall)
```

This doesn't work, in that it doesn't return a list of strings with substituted text, but I don't understand why it doesn't work.

My question/s are:

- What am I doing wrong in the above example?
- Is there a better way to approach the problem of doing a large number of substitutions involving long-ish strings?

(NB I may have missed the obvious here as I've only been looking at Python for a couple of days; my background is in R and Perl.)

Comment: What is the output of `print(newall)`?

Comment: Nevermind, what your solution does is some sort of cartesian product of the items in `all` and the items in `mydict`. See the answers for solutions :)

Comment: Btw, `all` is a python built-in function that you may not want to override.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

List comprehensions with two lists are nasty. They're error-prone and hard to read. Why not simply use two loops?:

```
all = ("this line has no hits",
       "a letter to tom from peter",
       "today bonny went to school",
       "harry made some cake")

mydict = {'harry':'sally','tom':'jerry','bonny':'clyde'}

output = []
for line in all:
    for search, replace in mydict.items():
        line = re.sub(search, replace, line)
    output.append(line)

print(output)
```

> ['this line has no hits', 'a letter to jerry from peter', 'today clyde went to school', 'sally made some cake']

Comment: Right. mixed with python2 here. Should be okay now.

Comment: I would change `all` to something else, that's a [built-in method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=all#all) name.

Comment: I'd agree, but since this seems like a one-off script I wanted to follow the OP's naming

Answer (score 0):

You need to use another functional programming concept, reduce.

You want to apply **each** key-value in mydict, one after the other, to the same string, resulting in **one**, final string. When this is the case (using a multi-valued dict/list/set to obtain a single answer), you use reduce. Like so:

```
import re

# copied from question
all = ("this line has no hits",
       "a letter to tom from peter",
       "today bonny went to school",
       "harry made some cake")

mydict = {'harry':'sally','tom':'jerry','bonny':'clyde'}

# define the function used in reduce
def replace_strings(line, mydictkey):
    return re.sub(mydictkey, mydict[mydictkey], line)

for line in all:
    print reduce(replace_strings, mydict.keys(), line)
```

And in list comprehension form:

```
newall = [reduce(replace_strings, mydict.keys(), line) for line in all]
print newall
```

There's some good basic stuff on functional programming constructs (reduce, list comprehension, filter): https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#functional-programming-tools

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I am using Python 3, which appears to not have `reduce`?

Comment: Hm, looks like you have to import and use functools: https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html

I guess it's explicitly non-recommended, but I quite like reduce personally